# Google apps or Gmail send and receive filters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Does Google Apps have something like a trigger on mail send/receive for Gmail like in spreadsheets? Something like a pre-send filter? I suppose nothing like this exists, right? What I'm interested in doing is to parse emails exchanged between members of an organization. Google has an Email Audit API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) but it needs the 3rd-party app to opt-in per sender/user.

The only way to do this according to me is to make every user authorize the app  and then make the app poll or push (IMAP-IDLE) to parse all the emails in each user's inbox.

Let me put it this way, is it possible (in Google Apps Mail) to create a mailing list like system without a common email address for the whole group? For example, can an organization post every email conversation between it's members to a common bulletin board?

To be more specific, the app will parse all the emails, look for some signals using some NLP and then take some action if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write an app that uses the Gmail Service in Google Apps Script. Each user would grant access and then your app can look at their emails for the content and then send that information to a common source.

GoogleScriptExamples.com

Comment: I know that but it'll have to run like CRON or something. I mean, it can use a clock based trigger right? AFAIK, there is no pre/post send or receive trigger in gmail for google apps, right?

Comment: No the trigger can't happen from Gmail but you could check the sent and All folders for new messages by date. Yes you need to use a timer trigger in Apps Script, very easy to set up.